# Show/Hide images based on tab selection

Tags: html, css, show-hide

I have some tab set up and I'm having a hard time figuring how to show/hide images depending on which tab is selected.  When the page loads tab1 and img1 are visible.  When I click on tab2 I want to hide img1 and show img2 etc.

This example shows what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/NbyXb/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="tab-area" class="light">

    <div class="dummy" id="first">
        <input type="radio" name="pane" id="p1" />
        <div class="dummy" id="second">
            <input type="radio" name="pane" id="p2" />
            <div class="dummy" id="third">
                <input type="radio" name="pane" id="p3" />
                <div class="dummy" id="fourth">
                    <input type="radio" name="pane" id="p4" />
                    <div class="dummy">

                        <ul class="tabs">                       
                            <li id="tab1"><span class="active" tabindex="1"></span><label for="p1">Tab1</label></li>
                            <li id="tab2"><span class="active" tabindex="1"></span><label for="p2">Tab2</label></li>
                            <li id="tab3"><span class="active" tabindex="1"></span><label for="p3">Tab3</label></li>
                            <li id="tab4"><span class="active" tabindex="1"></span><label for="p4">Tab4</label></li> 
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-strip"></div>

                        <div class="panes-scroll">
                            <div class="panes-items">
                                <div id="pane1">
                                    <h2>Tab 1 area</h2>        
                                </div>

                                <div id="pane2">
                                    <h2>Tab 2 area</h2>
                                </div>

                                <div id="pane3">
                                    <h2>Tab 3 area</h2>
                                </div>

                                <div id="pane4">
                                    <h2>Tab 3 area</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end of .panes-items -->
                        </div>  <!-- end of .panes-scroll -->
                    </div>
                </div>  <!-- end #fourth -->
            </div>  <!-- end #third -->
        </div>  <!-- end #second -->
    </div>  <!-- end #first -->
</div> <!--end of #tab-area-->

<div class="images">
    <img id="tab1-img" src="images/img1.png">
    <img id="tab2-img" src="images/img2.png">
    <img id="tab3-img" src="images/img3.png">
    <img id="tab4-img" src="images/img4.png">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#tab-area {
    margin: 40px;
}

.dummy {
    outline: none;  /* For IE */
}

input[name=pane] { display: none;}

.tabs {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.tabs li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 38px;
    float: left;
    font: bold 14px Arial, sans serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.tabs li:first-child {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.tabs li:last-child {
}

.tabs li .active:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
}

.tabs li .active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 107px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
}

.tab-strip {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 10px;
    width: 700px;
}

.panes-scroll {
    width: 698px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 250px;
}

.panes-items {
    width: 2800px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.panes-items > div {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 660px;
    height: 0;
    font: 12px Arial, sans serif;
    float: left;
}

.panes-items > div:first-of-type { height: auto; }
.tabs li:first-child .active { display: block;}

input[name=pane]:checked + .dummy .panes-items > div { height: 0; }
input[name=pane]:checked + .dummy .tabs li .active { display: none;}

#p1:checked + .dummy .panes-items { 
    margin-left: 0;
}
#p2:checked + .dummy .panes-items {
    margin-left: -700px;
}
#p3:checked + .dummy .panes-items {
    margin-left: -1400px;
}
#p4:checked + .dummy .panes-items {
    margin-left: -2100px;
}

#p1:checked + .dummy .panes-items > div:nth-of-type(1) ,
#p2:checked + .dummy .panes-items > div:nth-of-type(2) ,
#p3:checked + .dummy .panes-items > div:nth-of-type(3) ,
#p4:checked + .dummy .panes-items > div:nth-of-type(4) {
    height: auto;
}

#p1:checked + .dummy .tabs li:nth-child(1) .active,
#p2:checked + .dummy .tabs li:nth-child(2) .active,
#p3:checked + .dummy .tabs li:nth-child(3) .active,
#p4:checked + .dummy .tabs li:nth-child(4) .active {
    display: block;
}

#tab1-img {
    display: block;
}
#tab2-img {
    display: none;
}
#tab3-img {
    display: none;
}
#tab4-img {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: And the proble/question is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with a little bit of javascript (jQuery to be specific) 
**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.tabs label').click(function(){
       $('.images img').hide();
        $('#tab'+($(this).parent('li').index()+1)+'-img').show(); 
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/EZ33Y/1/ (i replaced the images with actual images because the original ones didn't load)

Also, please note that generally even the tabs themselves should be accomplished via JavaScript. This allows further browser compatibility and is the standard method of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for your help and input Kevin.  I'm fairly new at this but I was under the impression the pure CSS was the best for browser compatibility.  I have some Java on my page and when I view it in IE it asks if I want to run it.  If the user says no, then the they will miss out on the Java stuff.

Comment: @user2760221 It is important to note that we're talking about JavaScript, not Java. These are two completely different things, and JavaScript (which is the kind of code I provided) should work without prompts or issues on sites, as I would say 92%+ sites use it.